# How to remove dns dependency from JS code

Tags: javascript

New to JS, found some sample code and  modified it to suit to my purpose [1]. It is working fine, however the *dns.reverse(IP, (err) * is completely irrelevant for my code. Basically, I do not need **dns** module at all. I tried removing it several ways, did not work. Every time the code broke down. 
Ideas, how one could remove this unnecessary piece?

Many thanks in advance,

[1]

```
const dns = require('dns');                                                                                                                                                                                                        

const cache = {};                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
const crypto = require('./fpe');                                                                                                                                                                                                   
const cipher = crypto({});                                                                                                                                                                                                         


function reverse(IP) {                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    if (!cache[IP]) {                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        cache[IP] = {                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            promise: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {                                                                                                                                                                            
                dns.reverse(IP, (err) => {                                                                                                                                                                                         
                    if (!err) {                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                        const value = cipher.encrypt(IP);    // cipher.encrypt(IP) give back another IP of format xxx.xxx.xx.xx                                                                                                                                                                       
                        cache[IP].value = value;                                                                                                                                                                                   
                        resolve(value);                                                                                                                                                                                            
                    } else {                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                        resolve([]);                                                                                                                                                                                               
                    }                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                }); //dns.reverse                                                                                                                                                                                                  

            }), //promise                                                                                                                                                                                                          

        }; //cache[ip]                                                                                                                                                                                                             

        return cache[IP].promise;                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    } else if (!cache[IP].value) {                                                                                                                                                                                                 

        return cache[IP].promise;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    return Promise.resolve(cache[IP].value);                                                                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  


IP = "172.217.17.68"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
let temp = reverse(IP)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
temp.then(value => console.log(value))
```

Comment: What do you want your reverse() function to do instead of using DNS to reverse an IP?

Comment: I do not need any reverse function,its part of  sample code , all I need is these 3 lines "const value = cipher.encrypt(IP);                                                                                                                                                                         
                        cache[IP].value = value;                                                                                                                                                                                   
                        resolve(value);" along with the rest ofcouese.

Comment: how this function to be minimized to its purpose in the code? Or what other common function I could use to replace it.

Comment: If neither you nor any of the code from the sample you copied ever calls the reverse function, you can simply remove it, or comment it out. You can then look at the dns module you are importing using require('dns') at the top- if that is never used, you can remove that too.

Comment: if I remove dns module and comment "                dns.reverse(IP, (err) => {                                                                                                                                                                                         
", code fails to run with error ""(node:14776) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

Comment: Allright then let's try to resolve that issue. It probably is in the `cache[IP].value = value;` line (in the comment you posted). You are trying to set the value of the cache, but since the `reverse` function is now gone, there is no entry in the cache, hence the error. The reverse function used the cache for optimization. Are you ever using the cache? If not, you can remove the cache and also delete the line that caused the error (since if you never use the cache, there is no point writing to it).

Comment: Thanks Viktor, I do need the cache, and I want to store cipher.encrypt(IP) as value in cache[IP]. So I could use it second function (not posted here).

Comment: Allright, then maybe you can change it to `cache[IP] = {value: value}`. This will create the entry in the cache, and set its value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213613/discussion-between-pooja-and-viktor-w).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the DNS call like so:

```
function reverse(IP) {
    if (!cache[IP]) {
        cache[IP] = {
            promise: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const value = cipher.encrypt(IP);
                cache[IP].value = value;
                resolve(value)
            })
        }
        return cache[IP].promise
    } else if (!cache[IP].value) {
        return cache[IP].promise
    }
    return Promise.resolve(cache[IP].value)
}
```

However, this will lead to an error: Cannot set property value of undefined, on the line `cache[IP].value = value;`. This happens because the callback inside the Promise will be called immediately when the Promise is created, before the value is assigned to `cache`. Therefore, the cache entry will not actually have had time to have been created yet.

This is an easy fix though - since your code now is synchronous, no Promise is actually needed. We can remove the entire Promise and just apply the value to the cache.

```
function reverse(IP) {
    if (!cache[IP]) {
        const value = cipher.encrypt(IP);
        cache[IP] = { value: value };
    }
    return cache[IP].value
}
```

Note that this function no longer returns a Promise, so to use, do this:

```
IP = "172.217.17.68"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
let value = reverse(IP)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
console.log(value)
```